# c++ program crashing because of if statment

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

My c++ program is crashing i think because of an if statement. I am using MinGW compiler and am given no errors. I have no idea as to why i am getting the error. The if statement in my generate function looks fine to me. Im comparing a string with an instance of a vector string.

here is the cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "Insultgenerator_0hl14.h"

using namespace std;


FileException::FileException(const string& m) : message(m){}

string& FileException::what(){ return message;}

NumInsultsOutOfBounds::NumInsultsOutOfBounds(const string& m) : message(m){}

string& NumInsultsOutOfBounds::what(){ return message;}

InsultGenerator::InsultGenerator(const InsultGenerator& ) {};
InsultGenerator::InsultGenerator(){};

void InsultGenerator::initialize() {
    int cols(0);

    srand ( time(NULL));
    string words ;

    string filename("InsultsSource.txt");
    ifstream filetoread(filename.c_str());

    if(filetoread.fail()){
        throw FileException("File not read.");
    }
     while(filetoread >> words){

         if(cols==0){
            colA.push_back(words);
            cols++;
         } else if(cols==1){
            colB.push_back(words);
             cols++;
         }else{
             colC.push_back(words);
             cols= cols -2;
         }


     }


    //for (int i=0;i<50;i++){
    //  cout << "  "<< colA[i];
    //}
}






string InsultGenerator::talkToMe() const{
    string Thou = "Thou";

    string a= Thou + " " + colA[(rand()%50)] + " "  + colB[rand()%50] + " " + colC[rand()%50] +"!" ;

    //cout << a << endl;

    return a;
};//end talkToMe

vector<string> InsultGenerator::generate(const int num){

    if (num<0){
    throw NumInsultsOutOfBounds("You must be insulted at least once");
} else if (num >10000 ){
    throw NumInsultsOutOfBounds("You are being insulted too many times!");
}

    vector<string> insultList;
    string list;

     for(int i=0; i<num;i++ ){
         list = talkToMe();

        if(list != insultList[i]){
             //insultList.push_back(list);
             //cout << insultList[i]<< endl;
        }
     }



return insultList;
    };//end generate

    //int InsultGenerator::generateAndSave(const string filename, const int n) const{

    //};//end generateAndSave

int main(){
    InsultGenerator ig;
ig.initialize();
ig.talkToMe();
ig.generate(10);


    }
```

Here is the header file :

```
#ifndef INSULTGENERATOR_0HL14_H_
#define INSULTGENERATOR_0HL14_H_

#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class InsultGenerator{
public:
    InsultGenerator();
    InsultGenerator(const InsultGenerator&);
    void initialize() ;
    string talkToMe() const;
    vector<string> generate(const int) ;
    int generateAndSave (const string, const int) const;

private:
    vector<string> colA;
    vector<string> colB;
    vector<string> colC;
};

class FileException{
public:
    FileException(const string&);
    string& what();
private:
    string message;
};

class NumInsultsOutOfBounds{
public:
    NumInsultsOutOfBounds(const string &);
    string& what();
private:
    string message;
};

#endif
```

Comment: There's nothing in your vector, `if(list == insultList[i])` is accessing it out of bounds : undefined behavior

Comment: sorry i changed the if statement. it was supposed to be != . it still is having issues running

Comment: Still apply : you are accessing `insultList[i]` with `insultList` being an empty vector ...

Comment: @harmanlitt changing `==` to `!=` doesn't matter if you are accessing the vector out of bounds. I suggest you consider using the `at()` method instead of `operator[]` to access vector elements. (This is a general advice, not specific to this problem.)

Comment: I also noticed that you are using `throw()` without `try` or `catch`. What do you expect that to do?

Comment: Everywhere you use `50` in this program is most likely incorrect.  Vectors have a size, you should use it.

Comment: I wanted to throw an exception in num was out of bounds

Comment: @harmanlitt: In C++, exceptions are a way to report errors to other parts of the program.  They are not a way to show the user a message before exiting.

Comment: If you don't catch the exception, the system will call `std::terminate()` ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate ), which will stop the process but isn't required to print any message.

Comment: I had to downvote. See: [Some questions are still off-topic...](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you call the `operator[]` on your vector, you are trying to access an element of your vector. In this case the vector is empty, which cause an undefined behaviour.

```
if(list != insultList[i]){
```

Before trying to access your vector, make sure that this one is initialized with some values.

The index (`i`) you are looking for must be lower than the size of the vector `insultList.size()` (since the indexing start at 0)

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `insultList` to be of type `vector<string>`:

```
vector<string> insultList;
```

Then you're trying to access elements of `insultList`:

```
     if(list == insultList[i]){
         //insultList.push_back(list);
         //cout << insultList[i]<< endl;
    }
```

But nowhere in between do you actually add anything to `insultList` -- how many elements does it have?  Trying to access `insultList[i]` refers to unallocated memory which is causing your program crash.

Comment: wrong, the vector `insultList` is *initialized*, on the stack with a size of zero, there is no need to use `new`. However it is empty.

Comment: duh. thanks for that.  Seems someone else answered correctly but I'll edit just to avoid confusing people.